# Is it possible to execute a function for Acc2 in a Lambda in Acc1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I have two AWS accounts: Acc1 and Acc2.
Acc1 should transfer its secrets to Acc2.
By default, you can only transfer secrets to other AWS regions.
I want to create a AWS Lambda in Acc1, which fetches the secrets from itself.

In the same lambda function, the `secretmanager.create-secret` function for Acc2 should to be executed.

Finally, the secrets are to be replicated from Acc1 to Acc2, in only one lambda.

Is this possible, if yes how?

Thx